# No module named packaging.version for Ansible VM provisioning in Azure

Tags: python-2.7, azure, ansible

I am using a CentOS 7.2 and trying to provision a VM in azure through Ansible using the module "azure_rm_virtualmachine"  and getting the error as "No module named packaging.version" Below is my error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_7aeFMQ/ansible_module_azure_rm_virtualmachine.py", line 445, in 
    from ansible.module_utils.azure_rm_common import *
  File "/tmp/ansible_7aeFMQ/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py", line 29, in 
ImportError: No module named packaging.version

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "failed": true,
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_7aeFMQ/ansible_module_azure_rm_virtualmachine.py\", line 445, in \n    from ansible.module_utils.azure_rm_common import *\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_7aeFMQ/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py\", line 29, in \nImportError: No module named packaging.version\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
    "rc": 0
}

Below is my playbook and I am using a ansible version 2.3.0.0 and python version of 2.7.5 and pip 9.0.1

- name: Provision new VM in azure
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:

  - name: Create VM
    azure_rm_virtualmachine:
    resource_group: xyz
    name: ScriptVM
    vm_size: Standard_D1
    admin_username: xxxx
    admin_password: xxxx
    image:
    offer: CentOS
    publisher: Rogue Wave Software
    sku: '7.2'
    version: latest

I am running the playbook from the ansible host and I tried to create a resource group through ansible but I get the same error as "No module named packaging.version" .

Comment: Did you search anything on "No module named packaging.version"?

Comment: yes I have searched for "No module named packaging.version" , there was a similar issue but resolution was to run the run the playbook with delegate access to local .. where I have tried that as well .. but the issue still remains the same .

Comment: The issue is resolved .. I just installed Packaging library through pip and that resolved .. Thanks @Konstantin for the immediate response .

Answer (score 7):

The above error is occurred due to your environment doesn't have **packaging** module.

To solve this issue by installing **packaging** module.

**pip install packaging**

The above command will install packaging module of 16.8 version

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, it solved for me

`sudo pip install -U pip setuptools`

FYI: My ENVs are 

`Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS on Windows Subsystem for Linux (Windows 10 bash)
Python 2.7.12
pip 9.0.1
ansible 2.3.1.0
azure-cli (2.0.12)`